# Cómo puedo actulizar un campo en tiempo real, hay alguna forma más eficiente que usando ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

tengo un campo de la tabla que se llama hora_actual_logueo, y atravez de ajax, actualizo la bd guardando la hora cada segundo, esto me sirve para tener un control de ese usuario logueado, pero quiero saber de que otra forma puedo hacer esto, ya que si por ejemplo estoy navegando en diferentes paginas del mismo sitio, en varias pestañas, este hora varia, podria haber diferencia en segundos, entre un pestaña u otra.

no sé si hay otra metodologia para mantener una solo estado.

como si estuviera usando alguna variable de session de php.

agradezco sus consejos, y ayuda.

he estado investigando sobre si se podria hacer con websockets.

peor esto es nuevo para mi.

Comment: La pregunta luce basada en opiniones y eso generará su cierre, considera leer [ask]

Comment: bueno es que estoy buscando un metodo para mantener esa hora actual, entodas las sesiones de la pagina, porque me pasa que si abro varias pestañas del mismo sitio, la hora es diferente, restrasada o mayor porsegundos.

Comment: Y por que no buscas en el área de los websockets?

Comment: eh estado mirando pero no me queda claro como hacerlo con websockets